# Kernel density and polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, kernel-density, extract, multi-values

need a work around to produce a kernel density map of polygons (national parks system) layer at 30m grid cell and 500m bandwidth.  the kernel density tool in ArcGIS 10 does not work with polygons.

at this point i am thinking convert polygons to raster and use point estimate or focal statistics tool perhaps to extract the raster values (1 = park, 0 = no park).

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you would like to create a raster using the Kernel Density tool based on locations of National Parks?

If that is the question and you want a smaller scale map, I would just convert each polygon to a point using the [Feature to Point Tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-point.htm) and then run your Kernel Density with that file.